# Why does WaitHandle implement IDisposable explicitly?

Tags: .net, idisposable

System.Threading.WaitHandle (and hence ManualResetEvent etc) implement IDisposable explicitly. This seems to discourage it's use (calling Close() achieves the same as casting to IDisposable and calling Dispose).

I'm just wondering if there is a good reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's awkwardness in the .NET APIs induced by Dispose().  Other examples of classes that have both a Close and a Dispose method are the Stream derived classes, Socket, TcpClient, EventLog, Process, SqlConnection and many others.

I don't know any example of such a class that doesn't simply call Dispose() in its Close() method implementation.  In other words, you're always fine using the "using" statement and not calling Close.  The API designers however preferred keeping Close() around as a more literal way of ending the use of the object.  That's defensible, the Dispose() method tends to be inherited from a base class, often a very obscure one.

Comment: precisely - it's because of the developers' choice of the public interface of the type in question.  Dispose is, let's face it, a bit smelly; and in the case of a handle (especially for anyone that's done Win32 API work in C or C++ for example), 'Close' makes so much more sense.  It's also shorter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because calling Close is the preferred way of closing these kinds of system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes allow one to use Open and Close multiple times on the same object; some such classes, but not all, include logic so that calling Dispose will not only call Close, but also disallow any further calls to Open.

The authors of some classes may not have wanted to add logic to enforce the "can't reopen after dispose" rule, but wanted to leave open the option of doing so in future.  Since programmers who want to close and reopen an object are unlikely to cast to IDisposable to perform the close, it's pretty likely that anyone who calls IDisposable.Dispose on the object won't mind if it becomes unusable.  Consequently, nearly all client code which isn't deliberately written obtusely would continue to work even if IDisposable.Dispose were to invalidate an object to prevent reuse.  By contrast, if an object had both Dispose and Close methods available in its public interface, it would be far more likely that programmers might regard them as interchangeable, and use Dispose even in cases where they expected to reuse an object.